# snapping lines by order

Tags: qgis, postgis, grass-gis, snapping

I wish to clean lines with some attibutes like

order1 (red), order2(green)...
[image]

I use v.clean in QGIS for snapping. Is there a way (QGIS, GRASS, Postgis, Spatialite) that snaps the green line on the red line?

Answer (score 1):

Both QGIS and GRASS GIS offer a graphical vector digitizer. In addition, GRASS GIS offers a dedicated tool for vector editing ([v.edit](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.edit.html)).

If it is a one-time only operation, it will be easier to interactively snap the line (snapping function in the aforementioned digitizers).